# Deriving marginal distribution from a funky joint exponential-like distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, joint-distribution

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random variables such that
$$P(X > x, Y > y) = \exp\lbrack-(\lambda_1 x + \lambda_2 y + \lambda_{12} \max(x, y))\rbrack$$

What is the marginal distribution of $X?$

Source of problem is [here;](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Edeanweb/JRFSTATSQ2010.pdf) check problem 11 under section RSII.

I'm honestly at a loss for how to proceed. Hints or advice towards solving this would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd thought about something like that... does the non-negativity follow from P(X > 0, Y > 0) = 1, @Zen?

Comment: The non-negativity is not needed, but it of course follows immediately from the fact that the non-negative $(x,y)$ values have $100\%$ probability.  More generally, you find the marginal CDF of $X$ by taking the limit as $y\to-\infty$ and differentiate that to obtain the marginal density of $X.$

Comment: Understood, @whuber. I think I have a handle on this now, thank you!

Comment: For $x,y>0$, this is a bivariate exponential distribution due to Marshall and Olkin.